# $row=mysql_fetch_array and $row2=mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out a way of being able to use $row and $row2.  How can I incorporate that into the while statement?

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infupdates WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' ORDER BY date DESC");
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infupdates WHERE username='test' ORDER BY date DESC");
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_ASSOC))
<td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row[onetie]==1)) print "✓";?></span></td>
    <td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row2[onecro]==1)) print "✓";?></span></td>
```

Comment: Just a note: You should be using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` as the `mysql_*` is being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `OR` in query try

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infupdates WHERE '".$_SESSION['username']."' OR username='test' ORDER BY date DESC");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {?>
<td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row['onetie']==1)) print "✓";?></span></td>
    <td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row['onecro']==1)) print "✓";?></span></td>
<?php }?>
```

**Also check @vutran comment**

Answer (score 0):

while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_ASSOC) || $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

}

Otherwise use "UNION" in sql Query

Comment: thank you for mentioning Union it seems to make the most sense, now trying to get the formatting right

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR operator instead of using two queries.

```
<?php $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infupdates WHERE username='test' OR username=$_SESSION[username] ORDER BY date DESC");
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ ?>
<td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row['onetie']==1)) print "✓";?></span></td>
<td><span class="checkmark"><?php if (($row2['onecro']==1)) print "✓";?></span></td><?php } ?>
```